# How can I generate a PDB file within a C# program on Mac? Is there any way to do that?

Tags: c#, macos, pdb-files

I'm developing a compiler for a programming language of my own. I think it's almost as functional as any other programming languages. But when it comes to debugging, a problem arises.

When you debug your .NET program, you have to have PDB files in the same directory as the executable so I want to generate PDB files. But there seems to be no way to do that.

Usually, because an API of .NET supports generating PDB files (I mean `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod` which I think that generates PDB files if it accepts the second parameter) it should be an easy task, but because I'm using a Mac and because I want to make my programming language available on every platform, I can't use the API. When I used the API on Mac, an exception is thrown, and it said `"It's not available on this platform"`.

Meanwhile, when I googled I found `Mono.Cecil` and tried it, but it seems that it's for *reading* and writing PDB files, not *generating*. The fact that [this question gets no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770381/mono-cecil-error-generating-pdb) also tells you it may be true.

So the question is **"Is there any way to generate PDB files within a C# program on Mac?"** Any information will be appreciated, even *"implement it by yourself"*.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE on Apr. 15 2018**: After I searched through the Internet, I found that there is indeed no way to generate PDB files at present, at least until they implement `DebugInfoGenerator.CreatePdbGenerator`. So the next question is **"Is there any way to generate *MDB* files within a C# program on Mac?"** I'm wondering if some API from the `Mono.CSharp` namespace do the trick or not, but it's just a doubt. Does anybody know about it? And hopefully lead me to the right direction?

Comment: Are you generating .NET assemblies? If so, have you tried Portable PDBs using the `System.Reflection.Metadata` package?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating .NET assemblies using the expression tree. Ah, I saw that package somewhere, but because I couldn't figure out how to use it, so I haven't tried it. Maybe I'll give it a try! Thanks a lot!